# Building an SVM with Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, svm

I currently have two numpy arrays:

- `X` - (157, 128) - 157 sets of 128 features
- `Y` - (157) - classifications of the feature sets

This is the code I have written to attempt to build a linear classification model of these features.

First of all I adapted the arrays to a Tensorflow dataset:

```
train_input_fn = tf.estimator.inputs.numpy_input_fn(
    x={"x": X},
    y=Y,
    num_epochs=None,
    shuffle=True)
```

I then tried to `fit` an SVM model:

```
svm = tf.contrib.learn.SVM(
    example_id_column='example_id', # not sure why this is necessary
    feature_columns=tf.contrib.learn.infer_real_valued_columns_from_input(X), # create feature columns (not sure why this is necessary) 
    l2_regularization=0.1)

svm.fit(input_fn=train_input_fn, steps=10)
```

But this just returns the error:

```
WARNING:tensorflow:float64 is not supported by many models, consider casting to float32.
WARNING:tensorflow:Using temporary folder as model directory: /tmp/tmpf1mwlR
WARNING:tensorflow:tf.variable_op_scope(values, name, default_name) is deprecated, use tf.variable_scope(name, default_name, values)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/www/idmy.team/python/train/classifier.py", line 59, in <module>
    svm.fit(input_fn=train_input_fn, steps=10)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/util/deprecation.py", line 316, in new_func
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/contrib/learn/python/learn/estimators/estimator.py", line 480, in fit
    loss = self._train_model(input_fn=input_fn, hooks=hooks)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/contrib/learn/python/learn/estimators/estimator.py", line 985, in _train_model
    model_fn_ops = self._get_train_ops(features, labels)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/contrib/learn/python/learn/estimators/estimator.py", line 1201, in _get_train_ops
    return self._call_model_fn(features, labels, model_fn_lib.ModeKeys.TRAIN)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/contrib/learn/python/learn/estimators/estimator.py", line 1165, in _call_model_fn
    model_fn_results = self._model_fn(features, labels, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/contrib/learn/python/learn/estimators/linear.py", line 244, in sdca_model_fn
    features.update(layers.transform_features(features, feature_columns))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/contrib/layers/python/layers/feature_column_ops.py", line 656, in transform_features
    transformer.transform(column)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/contrib/layers/python/layers/feature_column_ops.py", line 847, in transform
    feature_column.insert_transformed_feature(self._columns_to_tensors)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/contrib/layers/python/layers/feature_column.py", line 1816, in insert_transformed_feature
    input_tensor = self._normalized_input_tensor(columns_to_tensors[self.name])
KeyError: ''
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Could you edit your question and post the full backtrace of the error?

Comment: @NiayeshIsky Updated

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Here's an SVM usage example which does not throw an error:

```
import numpy
import tensorflow as tf

X = numpy.zeros([157, 128])
Y = numpy.zeros([157], dtype=numpy.int32)
example_id = numpy.array(['%d' % i for i in range(len(Y))])

x_column_name = 'x'
example_id_column_name = 'example_id'

train_input_fn = tf.estimator.inputs.numpy_input_fn(
    x={x_column_name: X, example_id_column_name: example_id},
    y=Y,
    num_epochs=None,
    shuffle=True)

svm = tf.contrib.learn.SVM(
    example_id_column=example_id_column_name,
    feature_columns=(tf.contrib.layers.real_valued_column(
        column_name=x_column_name, dimension=128),),
    l2_regularization=0.1)

svm.fit(input_fn=train_input_fn, steps=10)
```

Examples passed to the SVM Estimator [need string IDs](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/linear_optimizer/SDCAOptimizer). You can probably substitute back `infer_real_valued_columns_from_input`, but you would need to pass it a dictionary so it picks up the right name for the column. In this case it's conceptually simpler to just construct the feature column yourself.

Answer (score 4):

- As the error says `self.name` is  an empty string and that empty string is not present in your dictionary that you are passing to `infer_real_valued_columns_from_input` that creates `_RealValuedColumn` object
- So What I found by debugging the error is that the `tf.contrib.learn.infer_real_valued_columns_from_input(X)` the X that you pass has to be a dictionary so that the `self.name` of `_RealValuedColumn` object is initialized by the key of the dictionary that you pass
- So this is what I did

  ```
    import tensorflow as tf
    import numpy as np

    X = np.array([[1], [0], [0], [1]])
    Y = np.array([[1], [0], [0], [1]])

    dic = {"x": X}

    train_input_fn = tf.estimator.inputs.numpy_input_fn(
        x=dic,
        y=Y,
        num_epochs=None,
        shuffle=True)

    svm = tf.contrib.learn.SVM(example_id_column='x', feature_columns=tf.contrib.learn.infer_real_valued_columns_from_input(dic), l2_regularization=0.1)

    svm.fit(input_fn=train_input_fn, steps=10)
  ```
- Now this removes the above error an but it gives a new error `TypeError: Input 'input' of 'SdcaFprint' Op has type int64 that does not match expected type of string.`

Comment: Thanks for your response. Although it seems to just state what my question is and then a code snippet from tensorflow.

Comment: Dude see my answer properly .... Your are giving x a dictionary when it expects numpy array

Comment: Unfortunately, that is not true.