# Building SVM with tensorflow's LinearClassifier and Panda's Dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, tensorflow, machine-learning, svm

I'm aware of this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49465891/building-an-svm-with-tensorflow), but it is for an outdated function.

Let's say I'm trying to predict whether a person will visit country 'X' given the countries they have already visited and their income.

I have a training data set in a pandas DataFrame that's in the following format.

1. Each row represents a different person, each unrelated to the others in matrix.
2. The first 10 columns are all names of countries and the values in
   the column are binary (1 if they have visited that country or 0 if
   they haven't).
3. Column 11 is their income. It's a continuous decimal variable.
4. Lastly, column 12 is another binary table that says yes they have visited 'X' or not.

So essentially, if I have a 100,000 people in my dataset, then I have a dataframe of dimensions `100,000 x 12`. I want to be able to properly pass this into a linear classifier using tensorflow. But not sure even how to approach this.

I am trying to pass the data into this [function](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/learn/LinearClassifier)

```
estimator = LinearClassifier(
    n_classes=n_classes, feature_columns=[sparse_column_a, 
 sparse_feature_a_x_sparse_feature_b], label_keys=label_keys)
```

(If there's a better suggestion on which estimator to use, I'd be open to trying that.)

And I'm passing data as:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,2,size=(100, 12)), columns=list('ABCDEFGHIJKL'))
tf_val = tf.estimator.inputs.pandas_input_fn(X.iloc[:, 0:9], X.iloc[:, 11], shuffle=True)
```

However, I'm not sure how to take this output and properly pass into a classifier. Am I setting up the problem properly? I'm not coming from a data science background, so any guidance would be very helpful!

**Concerns**

1. Column 11 is a covariate. Hence, I don't think it can just be passed in as a feature, can it?
2. How can I incorporate column 11 into the classifier as well, since column 11 is a completely different type of feature than columns 1 through 10.
3. At the very least, even if I ignore column 11, how do I at least fit column 1 through 10, with label = column 12 and pass this into a classifier?

(working code needed for bounty)

Comment: First point, the tensor flow LinearClassifier that you are using is deprecated, you should be using this one instead.https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/estimator/LinearClassifier

Comment: You mentioned "Let's assume none of the people in the data have already visited 'X'" and then there is a column if they visited 'X'. Does it mean this column is always zero? empty?

Comment: Sorry, I meant that is what we want to predict for.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

## Linear SVM

SVM is a max margin classifier, i.e. it maximizes the width or the margin separating the positive class from the negative class. The loss function of linear SVM in case of binary classification is given below.

[image]

It can be derived from the more generalized multi class linear SVM loss (also called hinge loss) shown below (with Δ = 1).

[image]
[image]

Note: In all the above equations, the weight vector `w` includes bias `b`

***How on the earth did someone came up with this loss?*** Lets dig in.

[image]

Image above shows the data points belonging to positive class separated from the data point belonging to the negative class by a separating hyperplane (shown as solid line). However, there can be many such separating hyperplanes. SVM finds the separating hyperplane such that the distance of the hyperplane to the nearest positive data point and to the nearest negative data point is maximum (shown as dotted line).

Mathematically, SVM finds the weight vector `w` (bias included) such that

[image]

If the labels(`y`) of +ve class and -ve class are `+1` and `-1` respectively, then SVM finds `w` such that

[image]

•   If a data point is on the correct side of the hyperplane (correctly classified) then

[image]

•   If a data point is on the wrong side (miss classified) then

[image]

So the loss for a data point, which is a measure of miss classification can be written as

[image]

## Regularization

If a weight vector `w` correctly classifies the data (`X`) then any multiple of these weight vector  `λw` where  `λ>1` will also correctly classifies the data ( zero loss). This is because the transformation `λW` stretches all score magnitudes and hence also their absolute differences. L2 regularization penalizes the large weights by adding the regularization loss to the hinge loss.

[image]

For example, if `x=[1,1,1,1]` and two weight vectors `w1=[1,0,0,0]`, `w2=[0.25,0.25,0.25,0.25]`. Then `dot(W1,x) =dot(w2,x) =1` i.e. both the  weight vectors lead to the same dot product and hence same hinge loss. But the L2 penalty of `w1` is `1.0` while the L2 penalty of `w2` is only `0.25`. Hence L2 regularization prefers `w2` over `w1`. The classifier is encouraged to take into account all input dimensions to small amounts rather than a few input dimensions and very strongly. This improve the generalization of the model and lead to less overfitting.

L2 penalty leads to the max margin property in SVMs. If the SVM is expressed as an optimization problem then the generalized Lagrangian form for the constrained quadratic optimization problem is as below

[image]

Now that we know the loss function of linear SVM we can use gradient decent (or other optimizers) to find the weight vectors which minimizes the loss.

## Code

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn import datasets

# Load Data
iris = datasets.load_iris()
X = iris.data[:, :2][iris.target != 2]
y = iris.target[iris.target != 2]

# Change labels to +1 and -1 
y = np.where(y==1, y, -1)

# Linear Model with L2 regularization
model = tf.keras.Sequential()
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation='linear', kernel_regularizer=tf.keras.regularizers.l2()))

# Hinge loss
def hinge_loss(y_true, y_pred):    
    return tf.maximum(0., 1- y_true*y_pred)

# Train the model
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss=hinge_loss)
model.fit(X, y,  epochs=50000, verbose=False)

# Plot the learned decision boundary 
x_min, x_max = X[:, 0].min() - 1, X[:, 0].max() + 1
y_min, y_max = X[:, 1].min() - 1, X[:, 1].max() + 1
xx, yy = np.meshgrid(np.arange(x_min, x_max, 0.01),
                         np.arange(y_min, y_max, 0.01))
Z = model.predict(np.c_[xx.ravel(), yy.ravel()])
Z = Z.reshape(xx.shape)
cs = plt.contourf(xx, yy, Z, cmap=plt.cm.coolwarm, alpha=0.8)
plt.scatter(X[:, 0], X[:, 1], c=y, cmap=plt.cm.Set1)
plt.show()
```

[image]

SVM can also be expressed as a constrained quadratic optimization problem. The advantage of this formulation is that we can use the kernel trick to classify non linearly separable data (using different kernels). LIBSVM implements the Sequential minimal optimization (SMO) algorithm for kernelized support vector machines (SVMs).

## Code

```
from sklearn.svm import SVC
# SVM with linear kernel
clf = SVC(kernel='linear')
clf.fit(X, y) 

# Plot the learned decision boundary 
x_min, x_max = X[:, 0].min() - 1, X[:, 0].max() + 1
y_min, y_max = X[:, 1].min() - 1, X[:, 1].max() + 1
xx, yy = np.meshgrid(np.arange(x_min, x_max, 0.01),
                         np.arange(y_min, y_max, 0.01))
Z = model.predict(np.c_[xx.ravel(), yy.ravel()])
Z = Z.reshape(xx.shape)
cs = plt.contourf(xx, yy, Z, cmap=plt.cm.coolwarm, alpha=0.8)
plt.scatter(X[:, 0], X[:, 1], c=y, cmap=plt.cm.Set1)
plt.show()
```

[image]

## Finally

The Linear SVM model using tf which you can use for your problem statement is

```
# Prepare Data 
# 10 Binary features
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,2,size=(1000, 10)))
# 1 floating value feature 
df[11] = np.random.uniform(0,100000, size=(1000))
# True Label 
df[12] = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0, 2, size=(1000)))

# Convert data to zero mean unit variance 
scalar = StandardScaler().fit(df[df.columns.drop(12)])
X = scalar.transform(df[df.columns.drop(12)])
y = np.array(df[12])

# convert label to +1 and -1. Needed for hinge loss
y = np.where(y==1, +1, -1)

# Model 
model = tf.keras.Sequential()
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation='linear', 
                                kernel_regularizer=tf.keras.regularizers.l2()))
# Hinge Loss
def my_loss(y_true, y_pred):    
    return tf.maximum(0., 1- y_true*y_pred)

# Train model 
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss=my_loss)
model.fit(X, y,  epochs=100, verbose=True)
```

## K-Fold cross validation and making predictions

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn import datasets
from sklearn.model_selection import KFold
from sklearn.metrics import roc_curve, auc

# Load Data
iris = datasets.load_iris()
X = iris.data[:, :2][iris.target != 2]
y_ = iris.target[iris.target != 2]

# Change labels to +1 and -1 
y = np.where(y_==1, +1, -1)


# Hinge loss
def hinge_loss(y_true, y_pred):    
    return tf.maximum(0., 1- y_true*y_pred)

def get_model():
    # Linear Model with L2 regularization
    model = tf.keras.Sequential()
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation='linear', kernel_regularizer=tf.keras.regularizers.l2()))
    model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss=hinge_loss)
    return model

def sigmoid(x):
    return 1 / (1 + np.exp(-x))

predict = lambda model, x : sigmoid(model.predict(x).reshape(-1))
predict_class = lambda model, x : np.where(predict(model, x)>0.5, 1, 0)


kf = KFold(n_splits=2, shuffle=True)

# K Fold cross validation
best = (None, -1)

for i, (train_index, test_index) in enumerate(kf.split(X)):
    X_train, X_test = X[train_index], X[test_index]
    y_train, y_test = y[train_index], y[test_index]

    model = get_model()
    model.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs=5000, verbose=False, batch_size=128)
    y_pred = model.predict_classes(X_test)
    val = roc_auc_score(y_test, y_pred)    
    print ("CV Fold {0}: AUC: {1}".format(i+1, auc))
    if best[1] < val:
        best = (model, val)

# ROC Curve using the best model
y_score = predict(best[0], X)
fpr, tpr, _ = roc_curve(y_, y_score)
roc_auc = auc(fpr, tpr)
print (roc_auc)

# Plot ROC
plt.figure()
lw = 2
plt.plot(fpr, tpr, color='darkorange',
         lw=lw, label='ROC curve (area = %0.2f)' % roc_auc)
plt.plot([0, 1], [0, 1], color='navy', lw=lw, linestyle='--')
plt.xlim([0.0, 1.0])
plt.ylim([0.0, 1.05])
plt.xlabel('False Positive Rate')
plt.ylabel('True Positive Rate')
plt.legend(loc="lower right")
plt.show()

# Make predictions
y_score = predict_class(best[0], X)
```

## Making predictions

Since the output of the model is linear we have to normalize it to probabilities to make predictions. If it is a binary classification we can use `sigmoid` of if it is a multiclass classification then we can use `softmax`. Below code is for binary classification

```
predict = lambda model, x : sigmoid(model.predict(x).reshape(-1))
predict_class = lambda model, x : np.where(predict(model, x)>0.5, 1, 0)
```

## References

1. [CS231n](http://cs231n.github.io/linear-classify/)

## Update 1:

To made the code compatible with tf 2.0 the datatype of `y` should be same as `X`. To do this, after line `y = np.where(.....` add the line `y = y.astype(np.float64)`.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer, very informative. Two quick clarifications. I looked at the validation parameters and it doesn't have option for cross-validation. Is  this possible when I train (with regards to TF)? I'd like to incorporate AUC metric, but for that I need a proper validation method.

Comment: Also, in order to use AUC, the predictions have to be between [0 1]. But these predictions are linear. Is there a way I can map them?

Comment: Also a line about how to predict for my situation would be helpful.

Comment: @Jonathan, To  make predictions you can use sigmod/softmax to covert it into probabilities. Updated the answer with additional information.

Comment: @Jonathan, don't forget to accept an answer if it solves your problem.

Comment: Thank you. @mujjiga Lastly, is there a reason why you're mapping the binary output of labels to 1 and -1?

Comment: @Jonathan the hinge loss formulation uses labels 1 and -1 for loss calculation. Its so in the literature.

Comment: Awarded! Thank you so much!

Comment: The code gives an error with tensorflow 2.0 "Input 'y' of 'Mul' Op has type float32 that does not match type int32 of argument 'x'."

Comment: @amarnathchatterjee please see the `update 1` in the answer

Answer (score 1):

Since all of your features are already numerical you can use them as they are.

```py
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,2,size=(100, 12)), columns=list('ABCDEFGHIJKL'))
df['K'] = np.random.random(100)
nuemric_features = [tf.feature_column.numeric_column(column) for column in df.columns[:11]]
model = tf.estimator.LinearClassifier(feature_columns=nuemric_features)
tf_val = tf.estimator.inputs.pandas_input_fn(df.iloc[:,:11], df.iloc[:,11], shuffle=True)
model.train(input_fn=tf_val, steps=1000)

print(list(model.predict(input_fn=tf_val))[0])
{'logits': array([-1.7512109], dtype=float32), 'logistic': array([0.14789453], dtype=float32), 'probabilities': array([0.8521055 , 0.14789453], dtype=float32), 'class_ids': array([0]), 'classes': array([b'0'], dtype=object)}
```

The probabilities of the prediction output is most likely what you are interested in. You have two probabilities, one for the target being Flase and one for True.

If you want to have more details look at this nice [blog-post](https://www.guru99.com/linear-classifier-tensorflow.html) about binary classification with TensorFlow.

Comment: for column 'K', do I not need to introduce it as some form of co-variate? Or according to ML theory, it's better to just include that as a feature?

Comment: Can you please offer some explanation on how to interpret the output? That'd really make this answer more broadly useful.