# Node JS require trained in Python One Class SVM and use it for predictions

Tags: python, node.js, svm, tensorflow.js, one-class-classification

I need to train a One Class SVM model for an anomaly detection task in Python, export it (for ex. using pickle or tfjs-converter) and require it into a NodeJS function just for predictions.

I have tried using TensorflowJS library but it only works for Tensorflow/Keras models (ie. Deep Learning models) while OC-SVM is only included in Python's Scikit-Learn library.

I have found npm packages for training a One-Class SVM before using it for predictions through node, but thats not what I need.

I desperately need to find a way to do this. Any ideas?

Comment: You can use tensorflow to create [svm models](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49465891/building-an-svm-with-tensorflow) as well! Save your model and than as you mentioned use the [tfjs-converter](https://github.com/tensorflow/tfjs/tree/master/tfjs-converter) to convert it to a model that is usable in TensorflowJS.

Comment: You might wanna add the [tensorflow.js] tag :)

Comment: Thanks for the reply but tf.contrib has moved out of Tensorflow starting Tensorflow 2.0 alpha.

Comment: I even tried to convert my sklearn one-class-svm to ONNX and then to Tensorflow but the last convertion failed as machine learning operators are not supported according to an open issue on onnx-tensorflow GitHub page. Then I tried to load the onnx model through onnx.js but it failed as well..